# tsc --out weird behavior when using 'import' in my files

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have two typescript files, `app.ts`, and `angular2.d.ts' (which contains type definitions for angular2)

my `tsconfig.json` file looks like so:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "out": "public/all.js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "watch": true,
    "target": "ES5"
},
"files": [
    "typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts",
    "src/app.ts"   
]}
```

Expected result - `public/all.js` would contain the compiled ts file.

Actual result - `src/app.js` file is created, that contains the compiled ts file.
`public/all.js` is also created, but it only contains the following line:
`//# sourceMappingURL=all.js.map` (i.e. just the source mapping, no actual code)

When investigating further, the problematic line is:
`import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';` in `src/app.ts`. as soon as I remove that line everything compiles correctly. as soon as i put it back - it causes the aforementioned problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `tsc --out all.js app.ts`?

Comment: i'm using it without app.ts to make sure it compiles everything in my folder, as i have angular2.d.ts also in typings folder. however, when i did what u suggested it worked, which led me to understand that the actual problem is with the `import` directive (`import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';`). as soon as i put it there, it creates the aforementioned problem. I'm updating my question

Comment: I imagine that the compiler needs a starting point, otherwise the dependency tree would be unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings `"out":"public/all.js"` and `"module":"commonjs"` are mutually exclusive. You should either:

1. Use internal modules and let the compiler concatenate output file for you (remove `module` setting from config);
   [@basarat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat) would [advise](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md) you against it, but I think it's not that bad, especially for small projects.
2. Use external modules and concatenate output files with other tools (set `"outDir":"public/"` and remove `out` setting from config).

`commonjs` modules are meant for `Node.js`, `amd` modules are meant for `require.js`. If you're doing frontend development, it's best to use `amd` or internal modules.

Comment: what are external/internal modules?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules
Basically, internal modules are just compiled JS, while external modules provide some sort of wrapping for common module systems (`commonjs` or `amd`).

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the file

```
tsc app.ts --out all.js
```